# adding an object that represents users to an array after signup using passport

Tags: javascript, arrays, authentication, mongoose, passport.js

I am trying to make a list of username and passwords so that when a user signs in with their credentials they can see all the data that everyone else sees but they still have to use their own credential. I wanted to make a list of objects like this  `users : [{username : "user1", password : "pass1"}, {username : "user2", password : "pass2"}]`. this should be created on signup. I though [subdocs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) would help but I'm not getting what I want. I have this:

```
var userlist = new mongoose.Schema({username: String, password : String })
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    users : [userlist]
})
```

and I attempted to add the new users to the array like this:

```
app.post("/signup", function(req, res){
    var user = new User;
    user.users.push({username : req.body.username, password : req.body.password})
    user.save(function(err){
        if(err) return handleError(err);
        console.log("success")
    })
    // User.create(users : [{username : req.body.username, password : req.body.password}], function(err, doc){
    //  console.log(doc);

    // })
    res.redirect("/login")
})
```

this givs me this

```
> db.users.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56ba6219763de71c03199a70"),
        "users" : [
                {
                        "username" : "user1",
                        "password" : "pass1",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("56ba6219763de71c03199a71")
                }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56ba6225763de71c03199a72"),
        "users" : [
                {
                        "username" : "user2",
                        "password" : "pass2",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("56ba6225763de71c03199a73")
                }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}
>
```

It's making separate documents. I want it to look like this

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56ba6219763de71c03199a70"),
        "users" : [
                {
                        "username" : "user1",
                        "password" : "pass1",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("56ba6219763de71c03199a71")
                },                    
                {
                        "username" : "user2",
                        "password" : "pass2",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("56ba6225763de71c03199a73")
                }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}
```

Having the objectIDs in the subdocs are not so important to me . I just want to group all the users together so that when they go to login I could do something like if the doc is there the credentials are good so continue to other parts of website.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have resolved you question by now or not, regardless here is the answer to your problem.

Firstly if you don't need `_id` in `subdocument` then state that in the `schema` accordingly and no `_id` will be created.

```
var userSchema = new Schema({ username: String, password: String},{ _id: false });
```

If you use the above `schema` for `user` then there should be no `_id` field in the `subdocument`.

You should know that to insert a `subdocument` you need to know the `parent` for it. If you don't provide the `parent` while inserting the `subdocument` then for each insert a new p`a`rent is created. In this case parent contains `_id` and `users` subdocument. If I have the exact problem, I would go about solving it the following way:

The schema designs remain the same as shown below (I named them differently to avoid confusion):

```
var userSchema = new Schema({username: String, password: String},{ _id : false });

var userListSchema = new Schema({
  users: [userSchema]
});
```

Now I will declare the parent model as follow:

```
var UserList = mongoose.model('UserList', userListSchema);
//see below what list gets assigned. 
var list;
```

Now let's assume I have a route handler where I would like to keep adding the users upon sign up something as shown below:

```
app.get("/newuser/:username/:password", function(req, res) {
  //create user model 
  var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
  //load user module, for testing i use params, you can change this to req.body
  var user = new User({username: req.params.username, password: req.params.password});

  //I would like to find the first document in userlists collection 
  UserList.findOne({}, function(err, result) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    //below if condition is true, if there is one document with users subdoc
    if(result) {
      console.log('Found existing document with users subdocument. Adding user to array.')

       //assign the parent where the subdoc should be inserted to list
       list = result; 

       //there already is a document with subdocument users, so append to it 
       list.users.push(user);

      //save the changed list. 
      list.save(function(err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log('User saved.');
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No document found. Creating one and adding  this user to users subdocument.');
      // initialize list model with first ever user 
      list = new UserList({ users: [user] });

      //save the new changed list
      list.save(function(err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log('User saved.');
      });
    }
  })
});
```

Done. Now when I run the app and access the following URL for the first time

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/newuser/user1/pass1
```

The `userslist` collection would look as follow:

```
> db.userlists.find().pretty();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c349d6479f5b9b1eaea1c8"),
    "users" : [
        {
            "password" : "pass1",
            "username" : "user1"
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I would like to access the link with different params as shown below:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/newuser/user2/pass2
```

And the output of the collection looks as follow:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c349d6479f5b9b1eaea1c8"),
    "users" : [
        {
            "password" : "pass1",
            "username" : "user1"
        },
        {
            "password" : "pass2",
            "username" : "user2"
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 1
}
```

Now I terminate the app and then re-run the app and access the following url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/newuser/user7/pass7
```

And the output of the collection looks as follow:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c349d6479f5b9b1eaea1c8"),
    "users" : [
        {
            "password" : "pass1",
            "username" : "user1"
        },
        {
            "password" : "pass2",
            "username" : "user2"
        },
        {
            "password" : "pass7",
            "username" : "user7"
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 2
}
```

There you go. I feel bad to see that `userlists` collection would always always always have one `document` and its array would keep expanding, maybe not a good practice to solve your issue in this manner. If I were you, I would store each user as a single `record` and then do the group by or any other `aggregation` operation.